# How to deal with the error of adb connect?

Tags: android, adb

I can connect with adb connect before. But after I restart computer and connect again it has the error:
[image]

There is no adb server in task manager. So it is no use with adb kill-server. I did not connect usb and can not restart adb.

Is there other solution except restart computer?

Comment: Please specify the problem. After you restart what? Phone or desktop?

Comment: Thanks very much~ i restart desktop.

Comment: The way it works is: 1. You have the wireless ADB app on your device (ADB Konnect/ ADB wireless). 2. Both your device and desktop are connected to the same wifi network. 3. Start wireless debugging from device, and get the IP, Port 4. Use 'adb connect ip:port'. After restarting desktop, did you ensure that the computer and device are connected to the same wifi network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your USB is not connected so i can assume, you are trying to connect it over wifi.

1) For connecting your device over wifi, your android device needs to be **rooted**

2) Download emulator for your android device from the play store.

3) Write below code in emulator.

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

4) Now open your Terminal and try to connect it again. It should work like a charm. But make sure that given IP address is correct for your android device.

**If still problem persist** , you can try this.
There are many third party apps on the play store which will be useful to have a look.

Ex. [adbWireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless&hl=en) , [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en)

Comment: Can we run the above command on the device on start up or make a batch file and run it?